# Embed the newsletter page into a page template

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I have got on how to visualize the newsletter on a CMS Web Site.

the requirements:

- Building a newsletter
- Allow the user to visualize the newsletter on his browser
- Newsletter page part of a CMS Web Site.
- CMS pages are identical - Header / Menu for navigation .... + the main content that will change (One page it will be simple text / another page will show the article and another page will show the newsletter)

What I have done:

- I have built a newsletter via ECM module.  The newsletter is sent
  correctly to a group. (Dispatch the newsletter, the newsletter has
  been moved to the Send /2012/11 folder).
- When the user click on the
  link "View the newsletter into the online mode, they are redirected
  correctly to the online page.

As mentionned in the requirement, I need to see the newsletter in a Web Page. The main content should refer the newsletter.aspx.

My assumption was to use one layout and throught a parameter (like OnlineMode = true) I would show the Header or not. 
On Outlook, the header will not be shown and once the user will click to visualize the newsletter on the CMS, the header and menu will be shown.

Or, do I have to refer the newsletter page to another layout (which will contain the header and the menu) ? -> map the newsletter.aspx to the placeholder MainContent ?

Thank you,

Comment: Hello, I will try to work with a custom device (/Layouts/Devices) and for that new device, I will attach a new layout page and insert the sub layout which i will need to show for the online mode. I will let you know more information once it will work.

Answer (score 1):

`Util.IsMessageBodyRequest()` returns `false` for a usual web page request. It returns `true` for a "message" request. You can use it in your controls (sublayouts).